# Custom Geometry Mesh -- How to Triangulate in Order to Look Smooth

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

EDIT: Altering the subdivision count seems to have smoothened the surface. However, my surface now seems to have shrunk... I can't seem to get it back to it's normal size. Why does this happen and how can I fix the effect?

I'm hoping to draw hundreds of smooth-looking planes sequentially in 3D space to model data. These planes will all look slightly different, but for each one I am only given the 4 corners of the plane -- plus an arbitrary point in the middle of the plane to give the surface a slight curvature for aesthetic appeal.

Thanks to help from this site, I've triangulated a surface somewhat, but it looks like a pyramid. Here's what I have so far:

```
    var vertices = [SCNVector3(x: -5, y: 5, z: 0),
                    SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 5, z: -5),
                    SCNVector3(x: 5, y: 5, z: 0),

                    SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 5, z: 5),
                    SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 7, z: 0)]

    var indices : [CInt] = [4,0,1,
                            4,1,2,
                            4,2,3,
                            4,3,0]

    var normals = [SCNVector3]()
    var normalMap = [Int : SCNVector3]()
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.count; i++) {
        var origVec = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
        normalMap.updateValue(origVec, forKey: i)
    }


    //CALCULATE FACE NORMALS -->
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.count - 2; i++) {
        var p1 = vertices[i] //B
        var p2 = vertices[i + 1] //A
        var p3 = vertices[vertices.count - 1] //C

        var vector1 = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        var vector2 = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

        vector1.x = p1.x - p2.x
        vector1.y = p1.y - p2.y
        vector1.z = p1.z - p2.z

        vector2.x = p3.x - p2.x
        vector2.y = p3.y - p2.y
        vector2.z = p3.z - p2.z

        var faceNormal = crossProduct(vector1, v2: vector2)
        ((normalMap[i]!).x) += faceNormal.x
        ((normalMap[i]!).y) += faceNormal.y
        ((normalMap[i]!).z) += faceNormal.z
        ((normalMap[i + 1]!).x) += faceNormal.x
        ((normalMap[i + 1]!).y) += faceNormal.y
        ((normalMap[i + 1]!).z) += faceNormal.z
        ((normalMap[vertices.count - 1]!).x) += faceNormal.x
        ((normalMap[vertices.count - 1]!).y) += faceNormal.y
        ((normalMap[vertices.count - 1]!).z) += faceNormal.z
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.count; i++) {
            normals.append(normalize(normalMap[i]!))
    }



    //VERTEX SOURCE -->
    var vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices, count: 5)

    //NORMAL SOURCE -->
    var normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals, count: 5)

    //INDICES AS DATA -->
    var data = NSData(bytes: indices, length: countElements(indices) * sizeof(Int))

    //GEOMETRY ELEMENT -->
    var geometryElement = SCNGeometryElement(data: data, primitiveType: .Triangles, primitiveCount: 4, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(CInt))

    //GEOMETRY -->
    var geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, normalSource], elements: [geometryElement])

    geometry.firstMaterial?.doubleSided = true
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    self.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Since I would like for this pyramid-ish shape to look smooth, do I just need to hardwire many more triangles? If so, what's the "magic number?"

Or, is there some way to automate that triangulation process?

Or, perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree and merely need to look to improve the look of the model with lighting or shading or something of that nature. Would altering the subdivision count offer any sort of help?

Thanks for any and all help; I have never built custom geometries before.

Comment: If you can show me what you're trying to do, and what you've got, with screen shots, I can probably tell you what/why/how to deal with subdivision to retain shapes whilst gaining smoothness. But... I'm a visual thinker (designer) so your words are the opposite of transparent, for me.

Comment: Don't think I have the permission to share images, @Confused, sorry. Perhaps I can explain the current problem in more visual terms, though. I have achieved a smooth, 3d surface -- imagine a turtle shell inside of an ice cream cone. The current problem is that the edges of the turtle shell do not touch the walls of the ice cream cone because of increasing the subdivision count.

Comment: Subdivision pulls things inwards from extremities. In order to prevent this, you need to create another ring of polygons/verts right near the edge that you don't want to have distort too much when subdivided. Can you do that and still get a smooth outline to your turtle shell?

Comment: I could probably do that if I were only drawing one "shell" and if I knew where the vertices would be before hand. The problem is that I am drawing a whole bunch of them sequentially, and the vertices for each will be inputted realtime. @Confused

Comment: Given that you've used the turtle shell idea... can you crimp inside that shell, programmatically, by doing what's called an "inset" addition of an edge loop that goes all the way around the edge of the shell? If so, that's going to get you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve smooth results without subdivision is to average the normals of the vertices touching the adjacent planes. Ie, get the average of all normals in the same location.
It is not clear from the question whether this is an acceptable solution or whether each plane needs to be clearly distinguishable.

Here is a link describing the process (look at the bottom):
http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/terrain/index.php3?normals

In conclusion, each vertex should have the average normal vector of the surrounding polygons.

Comment: Thanks, @reden. I've summed and averaged the normalized face vectors surrounding each vertex. But my shape still looks quite angular -- each individual face is still visible.

Comment: Does increasing the number of triangular faces result in a smoother looking surface? @reden

Comment: Averaging the normals correctly should give you a smooth looking mesh. The contour of the mesh will still show the polygons, though. Just to be clear: You're averaging the normals around each corner? Not across the whole polygons neighboring each other? So, in the end, not all corners of a polygon has the same normals.

Comment: I'll enumerate my steps. I am calculating the normal for each triangle of the mesh. I normalize each of these face vectors. Then, to calculate the normal for each vertex, I add the normals of the vertex's adjacent faces together and then normalize the sum. So yeah, each vertex should have a different normal.

Comment: That sounds correct. I'm afraid I can't visualize what's wrong based on the information. Is the result any different from before?